# add " for all member of the last (1 and -1 positions)

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have a small problem with a list.
I did, that list={AA,BB,CC} and I wish to make it into the form of {"AA","BB","CC"}, but I cant insert ", because failing, I tried simply adding, or MapThreading, StringReplacing (% into "), but all fails...

Please, if you can help in this case... Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Not sure exactly, but `SymbolName` may be what you're after.  You might also have set up the list in not the best way to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = ToString /@ {AA, BB, CC}
```

> `{"AA", "BB", "CC"}`

should do it, but you won't see the quotation marks in the output cell, because *Mathematica* suppresses them in standard form output. To see them evaluate

```
str // FullForm
```

[image: fullform]